# How can I save current user to the database when a purchase is edited?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Question UPDATED: I am trying to save the id of the current user whenever a purchase is edited. Specifically when a purchase is marked as received.

I have a before_update callback to a method that saves the datetime when the purchase is marked as received, that works well, I just need to figure out how to pass the purchase editor's id to the database.

In user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :purchase_edits, :foreign_key => :purchase_editor_id
  has_many :edited_purchases, :through => :purchase_edits
  has_many :created_purchases, :foreign_key => :creator_id, :class_name => "Purchase"
end
```

In purchase.rb

```
class Purchase < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :vendor
  belongs_to :creator, :class_name => "User"
  has_many :purchase_edits, :foreign_key => :edited_purchase_id
  has_many :editors, :through => :purchase_edits, :source => :purchase_editor

  before_update :update_marked_received_date

  ## Saves date when marked received. ##
  def update_marked_received_date
    return unless received == true
    self.marked_received = Time.now
  end
end
```

In purchase_edit.rb (Join Table)

```
class PurchaseEdit < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :purchase_editor, :class_name => "User"
  belongs_to :edited_purchase, :class_name => "Purchase"
end
```

In purchases_controller.rb, (create & update), I have this:

```
  def create
    @vendor_options = Vendor.order("name ASC").all.map{ |u| [ u.name, u.id ] }
    @purchase = Purchase.new(purchase_params)
    @purchase.creator = current_user
    if @purchase.save
      redirect_to @purchase
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def update
    @vendor = Vendor.all
    @vendor_options = Vendor.order("name ASC").all.map{ |u| [ u.name, u.id ] }
    @purchase = Purchase.find(params[:id])
    if @purchase.update(purchase_params)
      flash[:notice] = 'Update successful.'
      redirect_to @purchase
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end
```

In Schema.rb

```
  create_table "purchases", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "vendor_id"
    t.datetime "created_at",                          null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                          null: false
    t.string   "order_number"
    t.string   "tradegecko_url"
    t.integer  "creator_id"
    t.boolean  "received",            default: false, null: false
    t.date     "estimated_ship_date"
    t.boolean  "closed",              default: false, null: false
    t.datetime "marked_received"
  end

  create_table "purchase_edits", id: false, force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "purchase_editor_id", null: false
    t.integer "edited_purchase_id", null: false
  end

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "email",                  default: "",    null: false
    t.string   "encrypted_password",     default: "",    null: false
    t.string   "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.integer  "sign_in_count",          default: 0,     null: false
    t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
    t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
    t.inet     "current_sign_in_ip"
    t.inet     "last_sign_in_ip"
    t.datetime "created_at",                             null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                             null: false
    t.boolean  "admin",                  default: false
  end
```

Comment: Why are you using `marked_received_by_purchases` is there a reason? Secondly I think keeping a boolean value or a timestamp for received would do the job.

Comment: @VaibhavDhoke I am using marked_by_received_purchases as the column marked_by_received_by_id is in the purchases table, I suppose I can drop the _purchases. I have a timestamp for received, I need to save the id of the user that marked it received so a boolean would not work.

Comment: Perhaps we misunderstood each other. I already have a timestamp for received, and received is indeed a boolean, that works fine. What I need is to save the id of the user who marked the purchase as received.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone else who comes across this question, (and my future self), this is how I got it to work:

First, in application_controller.rb:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

  before_action :set_current_user

  def set_current_user
    User.current = current_user
  end
end
```

Then in user.rb:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :created_purchases, class_name: 'Purchase', foreign_key: 'creator_id'
  has_many :received_purchases, class_name: 'Purchase', foreign_key: 'receiver_id'

  def self.current
    Thread.current[:user]
  end
  def self.current=(user)
    Thread.current[:user] = user
  end

  def purchases
    Purchase.where("creator_id = ? OR receiver_id = ?", self.id, self.id)
  end
end
```

Finally, in purchase.rb:

```
class Purchase < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :creator, class_name: "User", foreign_key: "creator_id"
  belongs_to :receiver, class_name: "User", foreign_key: "receiver_id"

  before_update :update_marked_received

  def update_marked_received
    return unless received == true
    if self.marked_received.blank?
      self.marked_received = Time.now
      self.receiver_id = User.current.id
    end
  end
end
```

Now, when a purchase is marked as received, the timestamp and user are recorded.

Answer (score 0):

```
Class Purchase
  belongs_to :created_by, class_name: 'User', foreign_key: 'created_by_id'
  has_one :marked
end

Class Marked
  belongs_to :purchase
  belongs_to :user
end
```

This could work in your favour. Moreover, you could keep the relation `has_one` or `has_many` marked, according to your requirement.

I would recommend you to create a different model for this because it will be easier to maintain and the approach you are trying to achieve is violation of [single responsibility principle](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/back-to-basics-solid#single-responsibility-principle). The  model Marked will have a foreign key of two models because it has a relationship belongs_to for both the model. Please have a look of [belongs to association](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-belongs-to-association).

Comment: I'm even more confused now. I still need one foreign_key in purchases table for when the purchase is created and I still need a separate foreign_key for when the purchase is marked as received in the purchases table. Wouldn't this serve to complicate things further?

Comment: You are partially correct. Please let me know if you have a clear picture now, I have edited my answer. Let me know if there is still any doubts.

Comment: Okay, I understand the belongs to association. What isn't clear to me is how introducing another model helps the situation. What would that model hold? Does it exist solely to create an additional intermediate relationship? How does Marked model solve the problem of needing to use two seperate user key columns in the purchases table? It seems like I am adding another problem to the existing problem. This is what I don't understand.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help. I made the new model and created the associations, but I still had the same problem. I still could not pass the current user's id to the foreign_key column in the purchases table when a purchase is marked received.

Comment: I actually gave up and got rid of the join table after I tried to get it to work. Also re-thinking how I have my existing tables set up. It is obvious to me now that I've been trying to do something that cannot be done the way I've approached it.

Comment: Okay, I have updated the question. I got rid of the previous code and added the new code. I am using a join table now, but still have the problem of passing the id in the update action of my controller. Please read the question again and let me know if this is better. Thank you.

Comment: Can you show the code for `purchase_params`. Also let me know the params you are passing from view, code of view will also be great  and give an example of problem you are facing, I mean are you getting any error while passing params or are you figuring out how to pass an id in update action from view.

Comment: Hello again Vaibhav. I tried a few different things over the weekend but it was of no use in the end and I reverted back all the changes I made so now I no longer have the tables set up this way. I would still like to figure out how to accomplish the goal of saving the user_id of the person who edits a purchase, but at the moment I have no idea how to go about it, so I have given up on it. Maybe in a few months when I've learned more I will be able to approach it again.